# Optimize CSS Delivery of the following

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
Your page has 16 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.
None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML.
Optimize CSS Delivery of the following:

Comment: And actually what is exactly your question? It's confusing to understand.

Comment: If you have 16 CSS-resources that are blocking, ALL OF THEM shouldn't be there. You should have _one_ CSS-file for each media (screen, print, whatever else you need) at the most. If all you care about is screen view, you need _one_ CSS file.

I assume you use Wordpress, or some other CSS malarky, so I would suggest you install a plugin that minfies and fixes these issues by combining CSS and javascript.

Comment: I think you forgot to add in your code at the end

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to minify your CSS files in a unique optimized file (Optimize CSS Delivery).

This will allow you reduce the number of http request to your server.

You can use tools like [Google Pagespeed Test](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) to have tips on how to further optimize your website.

Specifically for CSS minification you can use tools like Grunt or Gulp.